# Induce the Toggle Layout within Activity

Tags: android, toggle, navbar

Am trying to design an Activity with a Toggle Screen induced within.

Have a Main Activity and at the bottom of it have customized Navigation Bar for our app. We wish to have a toggle kind of screen underneath the MainActivity with the control of it being handed over to the button in the Customized Nav Bar as in the below ScreenShot.

[image: Design of our App]

How we plan to Design :
We plan to design a new Layout for the underlying Toggle Screen. and would show and hide when the User hits the button in Nav Bar.

Constraints of this Design:
We feel like this design would redraw the entire activity as the Contents of the MainActivity would need to adjust with the new content in the Toggle Screen and could hit the Performance.

Looked and Googled around and when it comes to toggle effect, find only the articles about default Toggle Button which wasn't helpful.

Is there any Toggle Effect that we can associate with the button in Nav Bar or any Alternatives please suggest.

Comment: Can you show me two states(toggle off/on) in your app?

Comment: @SweetWisherツ we don't have any built in toggle button. we planning to use an icon to work as toggle button. Is this approach right? Thx for the response.

Comment: Yaaaa I.got your point but wanna see what you want to achieve.  It would be great if you share some screens